# Jmyron and Windows 8

Tags: opencv, video, processing, webcam, jmyron

I am running into hardware issues that perhaps someone here knows a workaround. I am using a PC and windows.
For several years I have been making interactive installations using video tracking: the Jmyron library in Processing, which has functioned marvelously for me. I use this set up: cctv type microcameras to a multiplexer, the I digitize this signal via a firewire cable to a pci card. Then Processing reads these quads (sometimes more) as a single window, and it has always worked (from windows xp all the way to 7). Then comes windows 8: Processing seems to prefer the built-in webcam to the firewire bus. On previous version of windows, the firewire bus would naturally override the webcam, provided I had first opened a video capture in Windows Maker, and then shut it down before running the Processing sketch. In Windows 7, which had no native video capture software, I used this great open source video editor called Capture Flux. The webcam never interfered. With Windows 8, no matter what I try, Processing defaults to the webcam, which for my purposes is useless. I have an exhibition coming up real soon, and there is no way I am going to have the time to rewrite all that code for Open CV or other newer libraries.
I am curious if anyone has had similar problems, found a work around? Is there a way of disabling the webcam in Windows 8 (temporarily of course, because I need it to be operational for other applications), or some other solution?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
type "windows icon+x" choose device manager (or use run/command line: "mmc devmgmt.msc")
look for imaganing devices, find your integrated webcamera
right click on it and choose disable - now processing should skip the device.
Repeat the steps to reenable the device.

Other solution would be using commands in processing:
println (Capture.list()); (google it on processing.org) this way you will get all avaliable devices and you can choose the particular one based on its name.

Hope this helps.